# Цикличная смена текста с анимацией (jQuery)

Tags: html, jquery, slider, text, animate

Необходимо, чтобы определенный список текста циклично менялся аккуратной анимацией по времени.
Сейчас вот такая картина, из-за чего список сначала выводится полностью, затем убирается по одной из всех строк, а затем меняется, но не той анимацией, и смена контента влечет за собой "дерганье" всех элементов ниже данного текста.
Сделал гифку, чтобы сверять.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.welcome-text .meet').eq(0).addClass('active').fadeIn(50);

    setInterval('blockAnimate();', 4000);
});


function blockAnimate() {
    var length = $('.welcome-text .meet').length - 1;
    $('.welcome-text .meet').each(function(index) {
        if($(this).hasClass('active') && index != length) {
            $(this).removeClass('active').fadeOut(250).next('.meet').addClass('active').fadeIn(250);
            return false;
        } else if (index == length) {
            $(this).removeClass('active').fadeOut(250);
            $('.welcome-text .meet').eq(0).addClass('active').fadeIn(250);
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

```css
.meet {
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="welcome-text">
    <div class="meet">Встречайте,</div>
    <div class="meet">Meet,</div>
    <div class="meet">Wilkomen,</div>
</div>
<p>
Я контент, посмотри, как я двигаюсь здесь.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval('blockAnimate();', 3000);
});

function blockAnimate() {
  $('.active').removeClass('upnext')
  let active = $('.active');
  active.addClass('up');
  let next = $('.active').next('li').length ? $('.active').next('li') : $('.welcome-text li').first();
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  next.addClass('upnext active');
  active.addClass('hiddenclass')



}
```

```css
.welcome-text {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hiddenclass {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.meet {
  top: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
}

.next {
  display: block;
  top: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  position: absolute;
}

.up {
  display: block;
  animation-name: moveup;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.upnext {
  display: block;
  animation-name: moveupnext;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes moveup {
  0% {
    top: 17px;
  }
  100% {
    top: -50px;
  }
}

@keyframes moveupnext {
  0% {
    top: 60px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 17px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="welcome-text">
  <li class="meet start active">start</li>
  <li class="meet Meet hiddenclass">Meet</li>
  <li class="meet Wilkomen hiddenclass">Wilkomen</li>
</ul>
Я контент, посмотри, как я двигаюсь здесь.
```